# jQuery cancel event on keypress escape

Tags: jquery

From the example in my Fiddle you will see that I'm trying to once the user click on the button escape it will show the div status as cancel.

What I did was :

1. enter some value in the input box
2. just click on tab to run blur event (status is changed to saved)
3. change the value and then click on escape (the input is remove BUT the status is back to saved and not cancel)

I know it runs the code under the if statement for the escape event but after that it still goes to the blur event and change the status to saved.

See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bizonbytes/SYwpy/42/)

HTML:

```
<input id="input"/>
<div id="status">status</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').live('blur', function(e){
    $('#status').html("saved");
    $('#input').live('keyup', function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
        $('#status').html("cancel");
        $('#input').remove();
      }    
    });  
  });                                        
});
```

Comment: Did you change the Fiddle? It appears to work now

Comment: Also as a side note, you are putting yout `.live("keyup" ...` inside of the `.live("blur" ...` function.  It should be outside of that function.  See my example below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do the following it does not!

```
$('#input')
    .on('blur', function(e){
        $('#status').html("saved");  
    })
    .on('keyup', function(e){
        if (e.which == 27) { 
            $('#status').html("cancel");
            $('#input')
                .off('blur') // unbind the blur event
                .remove();
        }    
    });
```

[**Here is a forked demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/CrKEa/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AzGxG/)

It's the onblur event that's causing your problem.  When the textbox is removed, it triggers the onblur which sets the label to "saved".  You can amend this by adding a "canceled" class to the textbox and only save if not canceled

```
$('#input').live('keyup', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
        $('#status').html("cancel").addClass("canceled");
        $('#input').remove();
    }    
});  
    
$('#input').live('blur', function(e){
        $('#status:not(.canceled)').html("saved");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event fires when an input loses focus.  You will need to use the `keypress` event to pick up the ESC key event.

Comment: `keypress` doesn't pick up the esc key

Comment: `keypressed` doesn't pick up anything... `keypress` on the other hand, does (but @Joseph is right - not the esc key).

Comment: yeah, I realized I had mistyped it. It should be keypress